# How to add more Whitespace to the Main Panel in Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a couple of charts in my Main Panel in my `Shiny Dashboard`, and I was wondering how to extend the whitespace at the bottom of the main panel?  How should I modify my `ui.R` to do this?

[image]

```
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard",

              mainPanel(
                showOutput("plot3", "Nvd3"),
                showOutput("plot4", "Nvd3")

         )),
```

**Update:**
Adding `HTML("<br><br><br>")` in the Main Panel only created a wider dark panel:
[image]

Comment: Try including `HTML("<br><br><br>")` inside the `mainPanel`?

Comment: It made the dark space thicker, as shown in the Update.  Any other ideas?

Comment: How about if you change it to `HTML("<hr>")`?  It'll give you a horizontal line, but should be harmless?

Comment: That only added a think horizontal line at the bottom.  If I try to increase the thickness, I worry that it will overlap the chart...

Comment: What does the `server.R` file look like?

Comment: I don't think you need `mainPanel`.  That's a shiny function, not a shinydashboard function...

Comment: What about adding whitespace between the two charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS, in your ui.R file add:

```
tags$head(
   tags$style(
       HTML("#dashboard{margin-bottom:50px;}")
   )
)
```

Comment: What about adding whitespace between the two charts?

Answer (score 8):

Can you try to wrap you `showOutput` with a div wrap?

```
tags$div(
  style="margin-bottom:50px;",
  showOutput("plot4", "Nvd3")
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  Putting everything in a `fluidRow()` fixed it for me...

Answer (score 5):

For vertical whitespace in Shiny, you can go with `headerPanel("")`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and according to tip  **Jthorpe** I removed all `mainPanel`from my script. I have six plots one by one verticaly and it works fine.